# How do i prevent the textfield from changing id "myid" to "myid-tokenfield", Tokenfield for Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-tokenfield

I'm using Tokenfield for Bootstrap, and it keeps changing the id of my textfield from myid to myid-tokenfield.

This textfield needs to have a certain id in order to work with the search engine I'm using, so I really need tokenfield to not change my id.

Whatever ID I give the textfield, it appends the "-tokenfield" to it. I'm sure there's a good reason for it, but can it be prevented in a way without breaking it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The id is being set in tokenfield on line 105, shown here:

```
// Create a new input
var id = this.$element.prop('id') || new Date().getTime() + '' + Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 100)
this.$input = $('<input type="'+this.options.inputType+'" class="token-input" autocomplete="off" />')
                .appendTo( this.$wrapper )
                .prop( 'placeholder',  this.$element.prop('placeholder') )
                .prop( 'id', id + '-tokenfield' )
                .prop( 'tabindex', this.$element.data('original-tabindex') )
```

Where have you been changing the id that is breaking tokenfield? Have you tried creating a -custom.js version of tokenfield and changing the id there to see if it breaks?